# Linux IPV6 primary and secondary addresses

Tags: linux, interface, ipv6

I need someone to explain to me how the IPv6 addresses are assigned and treated as primary/secondary. Is it the same as it was with IPv4 - single primary, multiple secondaries or not.Is there an hierarchy among the IPv6 addresses assigned or it is a flat list.

Comment: The specific behaviour of course also depends on what you do in your code, but you haven't given any information about that. For a better answer it might be helpful if you include what you are developing

Comment: I was just wandering if I read all IPv6 addresses, is there primary/secondary among them or they are equal - I saw ip command flag and that made me think if it is possible to assign primary IPV6 address and secondary also.

Comment: If this question is not about how to deal with multiple IPv6 addresses when writing code (but about sysadmin stuff instead) then it is off-topic here. In that case please try e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: Please explain your concept of "primary/secondary" address and update the question appropriately with how you wish to interact with this programmatically.

Comment: I need to assign multiple IPv6 addresses per interface, in IPv4 there were one single primary address and multiple secondaries. Now I want to know if I add multiple IPv6 addresses would they be internally treated as primary and secondary, or not.

Answer (score -1):

It is a flat list. All other things like common prefix length equal and with no temporary (privacy) addresses Linux will usually use the last added static address as the default source address. You can override this by setting a specific `src` address on the default route:

```
ip -6 route add default via 2001:db8::1 dev ethic src 2001:db8::abcd
```

Answer (score -1):

It's weird:
According to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces you can define a primary and multiple secondary IPv6 addresses.

But the answer is still true. At least with Red Hat 8, the last secondary seems to become the default address. Also "ip a" lists the addresses in reverse order of their definition.

I guess that the reason for this is that the link local address is added first and to avoid it showing up first, someone decided to generally add new IPv6 addresses in front of the existing ones.